# The Stupid Computer Problem : can every polynomial be written with only one $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, optimization, visualization

When I was a child, I wanted to be a mathematician so I asked my parents to buy me a computer to make super complex calculations. Of course, they were not crazy enough to buy an expensive super computer, so they bought me a way cheaper *Stupid Computer™*. In the TV ad, they said that «*Stupid Computer™* can perform any operations a *Super Computer™* can do !».
As trusting as a 8 years old kid can be toward marketing, I trusted them.

In fact, and I realized that years later, Stupid Computer™ was just a Super Computer™ with a production defect.

With a Super Computer™ you can compute every polynomial functions like $ x^7-42x^3+3x$.

A bug in Stupid Computer™ prevents you to use the $x$ key more than once.
For example, you can't enter $x²+x$ but you can enter $(x+1/2)^2-1/4$ instead.

Super and Stupid computer can only use operations like addition, multiplication, exponent... and their opposite : subtraction, division, roots, logarithm...

The question is : **Can really a Stupid Computer do everything a Super Computer can ?**

Comment: If any polynomial could be written with just one $x$, you could solve any polynomial by radicals, which we know is false.

Comment: Can you do $x^5+x$ with this? (Also: are you French?)

Comment: @columbus8myhw You can't enter $x^5+x$ in a Stupid Computer because it has 2 $x$. And yes, I'm French. I guess you guessed right because of a French-typical English grammar error ?

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Can you please elaborate on what is "solving polynomials by radicals" and how do we know it's false ? Thank you !

Comment: If you have an equation like "$\text{formula}=0$" and there's only one $x$ on the LHS, you can solve for $x$ by reversing all the operations, ending up with a formula for the solutions of your equation in terms of reverse operations.  Just like how you get the quadratic formula from completing the square (as in your example).  But such formulas do not exist for the roots of high-degree polynomials; this was proven by Galois (but note that as [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) says, this is stronger than what we usually mean by "not soluble by radicals").

Comment: (I guess it's not entirely clear that solvability by radicals answers your question, since you have additional operations available.)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. While you couldn't do $x^2+x$ directly, you _could_ do $(x+\frac12)^2-\frac14$, right? Similarly, you can't do $x^5+x$ directly, but I was wondering if you could do something that equalled it.

Comment: (I suppose @columbus8myhw noticed your guillemets.)

Comment: @StevenTaschuk I think indeed that the fact that there is every additions and higher operations with their inverse available may surpass the radical solvability, but I can't see a way to prove it.

Comment: @Pyrofoux: Please note, that your example is *not* a polynomial due to the summand $\frac{1}{3x}$

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Corrected, thank you.

Comment: @Pyrofoux: You're welcome!

Comment: @Steven: Unsolvable quintics don't become solvable even if we allow exponentiation and logarithms in the solution, do they?

Comment: @Rahul: I would guess not, but I don't know.

Comment: @Steven: I think it makes sense to allow arbitrary (non-radical) real constants in the expression, in this case unsolvability by radicals does not solve the problem.

Comment: A fun problem would be to find the minimal number of x's allowed in an equation so that all possible polynomials can be formed. Is it 2? Is it finite/infinite?

Answer (score 7):

First, let's assume that [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel's_conjecture) is true and speak very loosely. :)

Timothy Chow's 1999 article [*What is a Closed-Form Number?*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~tchow/closedform.pdf) proves that the exponential and logarithm functions don't really help us to express algebraic numbers. Any algebraic number that can be expressed using those functions can also be expressed using only radicals. This is stated as Corollary 1 at the top of page 444.

So the expression $x^5-x$ can't be rewritten with a single $x$ using exponentials and logarithms. If it could, we would be able to solve the equation $x^5-x=1$ by inverting those functions, which means we could solve it using radicals, which is impossible.

Can we do without Schanuel's conjecture? Maybe. Chow hints at partial results that don't need the conjecture:

> It is folklore that *general* polynomial equations (i.e., those with variable coefficients) cannot be solved in terms of the exponential and logarithmic functions, although nobody seems to have written down a complete proof; partial proofs may be found in [C. Jordan, *Traité des Substitutions et des Équations Algébriques*, Gauthier-Villars, 1870, paragraph 513] and [V. B. Alekseev, *Abel's Theorem in Problems and Solutions*, Izdat. "Nauka," 1976 (Russian), p. 114].

I haven't tracked down those references. Maybe there's an equation where only the 0th coefficient is a variable, like $x^5-x+C=0$, that can't be solved in the relevant way. I'm not necessarily gunning for the bounty, so perhaps someone else can pick up the story from there?

Answer (score 3):

$f(x) = x^{3} - x$ is a counter-example. Assume for contradiction that there exist $\alpha, \beta \in\mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x) = (x + \alpha)^{n} + \beta$. Since $f(x)$ has degree $3$, we know $n = 3$. So $f(x) = x^{3} + 3 \alpha x^{2} + 3 \alpha^{2} x + ( \alpha^{3} + \beta) $. If $\alpha \neq 0$, then we have an $x^{2}$ term, and if $\alpha = 0$, then we have $x^{3} + \beta$. Neither works, so it cannot be written as such.

Comment: You are allowed to use more operations that that (like exponentiation), and also iterate them (like $((x+\alpha)^n+\beta)^m+\gamma$.)

Comment: I see, but I think the argument would still work, as $3$ is prime, so either $m = 1, n = 3$, or $m = 3, n = 1$ (still need a third-degree), so you're still curbing a first-degree factor.

Comment: that was just an example. And you also need to consider $e^u$, $\ln(u)$ and perhaps others. The OP is a little open-ended.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, we need only concern ourselves with algebraic functions (since we are, after all, trying to construct a polynomial, which is algebraic), which would exclude the exponential and logarithmic functions, as well as any trig business.

Comment: I agree that's likely, but the main point I think, is to make that precise.

Comment: I think that if we're limited to only using elementary functions, then it could be shown that you can't construct any more polynomials by showing that there are limit behaviors you couldn't get. That is, a polynomials limits at $\pm \infty$ are infinite, and I believe it could be shown (rather tediously) that you wouldn't be able to get certain desired end behaviors by composition with elementary functions. I can try to do it later. The limitation to elementary functions seems to be the most sensible one.

Answer (score 2):

> Can really a Stupid Computer do everything a Super Computer can ?

This is sort of an open-ended question. Here are some interpretations I have of it.

> Can the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ be represented as a power of a polynomial of degree one plus some constant.

<strike>Any expression using the field operations on $\mathbb{R}$ and writing $x$ only once can be reduced to some polynomial of the form</strike>

$$ (ax^m + b)^n + c $$

This is pretty straightforward to check, so I'll let you do that. The answer to this question is then no, as pointed out by user AJY in another answer.

**edit**: I made an error above as pointed out by user [David Speyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/448/david-speyer) in the comments below.

> Are we limited in what calculations we can do with Stupid Computer™?

Well, polynomials can be represented just as a sequence of coefficients, so there's actually no need to write $x$ at all!

> Each polynomial might have a real root. If we look at the set of all polynomials and the collection of all possible roots, is this root set the same for both Stupid Computer™ and Super Computer™?

Yes. If our polynomial coefficients are in $\mathbb{R}$ then it's not a realistic computer and trivially true since for any desired root $a$, the degree 1 polynomial $x-a$ has precisely the root we want.

However, this is even true if our coefficients are in $\mathbb{Q}$! The set of all real roots for all polynomials is just a linear combination of elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ and roots thereof.

Comment: Does the form you propose work for $(x^2+1)^2+1$, say? That doesn't have any odd powers of $x$, which your form can't avoid. Or am I being dense?

Comment: This is a very bad typo. You are completely correct. Thanks for catching that! Should be fixed now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. What about $((x+1)^2+1)^2+1$, say?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Well how about that. You're absolutely right. Noted above.

Comment: I think the comments accounted for said error.